# Detect specific word or pattern in source code files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I want to detect a specific word or pattern in all source code files. For example, if I want to restrict DateTime.Now to be used in the project, but if some team member has used this in the source code, I want to fail the build operation.

I don't know what is the proper way to do it, but can I use VS Pre-Build event for the same? If no, then can someone guide me on the correct path to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: I think the most "professional" but non-trivial way to do this is writing a [custom source code analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix).

Comment: An easier solution that won't fail your build but can fail your CI run (if you have one) is writing a unit test that searches all .cs files for occurrences of the unwanted stuff.

Comment: Running a script during the pre/post build event is also an option but I personally find them a bit too annoying to be practical.

Comment: Hmmm... let me check custom source code analyzer as I am not aware about it. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute PowerShell scripts by entering a command like `PowerShell MyPowerShellScript.ps1` in `PreBuildEvent`.The scripts include searching specific word or pattern in the all source code files.

Please follow the steps below.(example)

1. Powershell script

```
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path {your project path} -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "DateTime.Now";
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($results)){
  Write-Host "not found specific word DateTime.Now"
}else{
  Write-Host " found specific word DateTime.Now"
  #other than zero (0)
  exit 1
}
```

**Note**:

Have your event action exit with a code other than zero (0). A zero exit code indicates a successful action; any other exit code is considered an error.

2.Enter a command like `PowerShell MyPowerShellScript.ps1`.
On the Project menu->click {ProjectName} Properties (or from Solution Explorer, press Alt+Enter)->Select Build > Events.
[image]

Visual Studio modifies your project file by adding the PreBuildtarget and the necessary MSBuild code to execute the steps you provided.

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="PowerShell {your project path}\pw.ps1" />
</Target>
```

3.Build the project and watch the output window. If it finds the specific world(DateTime.Now) in your source code files, the script exits with code 1 and the build fails.
[image]

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks Dou Xu-MSFT for your answer. I think this what I want. Let me try it.